# whateverorigin.org | YQL | CORS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cors, yql

I have tried all three but for some reason they give error as cross domain access denied. I was using YQL on various places in my applications but its now not working either.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/13acuw9a/)**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?', function(data){
        alert(data.contents);
    });
});

</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Can work around or more reliable alternative?

Comment: Have you tried using `https`? It works for me if I use `"https://whateverorigin.herokuapp.com/get?url"`

Comment: is the error along the lines of `Blocked loading mixed active content "url"` - it doesn't help that whateverorigin.org is borken

Comment: `I have tried all three` - all three what?

Comment: I have tried it with `https` as well... all three mean `yql`, `cors` and `whateverorigin.org`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I think `whateverorigin.org` is broken but `yql` and cors not working either

Comment: "cors not working" - erm, yes it **is** working, and whatever site you are trying to "borrow" resources from is using "CORS" to stop you :p

Answer (score 0):

It's probably likely that the API that you are trying to access does not have CORS enabled.

You can consider using JSONP in your request AJAX request

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) { alert(data.contents); }
})
```

The other method, which is not a direct solution for you to do it through the client, is to create a server that does the API request through a route. The server would act like a proxy so that you can do an AJAX call to your server to do an API call to the endpoint that you are doing a GET request on. Of course, you would have to have CORS enabled on this proxy server.

In node.js it would look like something like...

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.get('/nameofroute', (req, res) => {
  axios.get('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?'
}).then(response => res.json(response))
  .catch(err => res.json(err))
}

app.listen(8080, () => { console.log('listening on:8080') }
```

And on the front end you would do an API to above server that you just created.